# Firefox Webapp (Open Web App) not working with self signed certificate

Tags: web-applications, ssl, firefox-os

I am trying to build an open web app using the information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Quickstart .

Installation seems to work (Linux desktop and Firefox on Android), but when opening the app I get the error message:

```
HOST uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.
(Error code: sec_error_untrusted_issuer)
```

The webapplication is indeed running on my webserver using a self-signed certificate. In the browser I can access the page without a problem (after adding a permanent security exception). Is this not possible with a web app? How can I confirm the security exception?

I searched the web but could not find any advice on how to solve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

You are hosting the app and its manifest at an HTTPS URL, yes? Do you see the same problem if the app and its manifest are hosted at HTTP URL's? This might be a case where we didn't implement the UI for apps to confirm security exceptions, as you suggested. But I could also argue that for security reasons we just wouldn't allow apps to use self-signed certs.

We are tracking this in our bug database:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=995005